# Trouble understanding ssh key gen man page - Specify location and password

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, debian

This is my code:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$APP"
```

This works perfectly. However it then asks me to specify location and password. I was hoping I can automate this all in one go, however this command fails:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$APP" -P "$SSHKEYPASS" -T ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

This command seems to fail though, when I specify the password I want for the key and location in the same line. I don't really understand the man page:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-P` is for the old passphrase, to create a key I assume you want `-N` for the new passphrase.

`-T` is for DH group test output it appears (not that I know what that is exactly).

You want `-f` to specify the key filename. And you specify the private key file not the public key file.

So try:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$APP" -N "$SSHKEYPASS" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```